# Will all Java Look And Feel work cross-platform?

Tags: java

I am trying to learn JComponents etc.

1. If I create a program in Mac OS with default Look & Feel ie., - UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName(), will my program work in Windows OS? I mean will the program automatically detect Windows L&F and run accordingly?
2. Again, If my program is created in Mac OS however with some non-native L&F (for example Liquid) - do I have to include the Liquid library in the jar file to make it work in other platforms?

Comment: 1. YES
 2. YES......................................

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you've already stated yourself,  and as the name already shows, the system look and feel is dependent on the system you are on and is already available there.

But you have to include any library in your jar, which isn't already installed by default on your target-machine. The 'styles' of the default look and feel are already installed in your java installation, so you don't have to include that. But Liquid has to be shipped in your jar.